# node.js error after switching to Windows - Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I switched from OSX to Windows 7. A project I'm coding is throwing an error which I believe to be related to the switch.

The first line below is the line causing the error to be thrown:

```
  if (!/not find/i.test(e.message)) {
    throw e
  }
```

The error is:

```
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Could somebody tell me how to get this line working in Windows?

Comment: Are you sure that the mentioned snipped causes the issue? You've probably downloaded [tag:node.js] for the wrong architecture (try again with the x86 version.)

Comment: Does your project use any compiled addons (either directly or indirectly)? If so, you'll have to rebuild/reinstall them.

Comment: Thanks guys, and sorry for the delayed response. I've tried both the x86 and x64 versions of node, based on another forum I was reading. My project does use a compiled module named "iconv" that's used in a bcrypt library I'm using. It was a pain getting it to compile, but I finally got the correct versions of Python and Visual Studio installed and it compiled.

Comment: @mscdex I just did a "npm rebuild" and I think that fixed this problem! There's another problem I need to figure out, but I believe the rebuild fixed it. Thank you! If you want to add an answer to this question I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy a project from one platform to another or you switch CPU architectures (e.g. x86 to ARM or x86 to x86_64), you'll need to recompile any addons that your project may have been using, either directly or indirectly.